# How to use the reverse function in python correctly for a caesar cipher?

Tags: python, function, caesar-cipher

I am currently doing caesar cipher in python. What I want to put to you is, how do I use the reversed function??

```
import string

text = input("Your message: ")    
print(text)    
alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
result = ''

for i in list(text.upper()):    
    if i in alphabet:      
        result += alphabet[-alphabet.index(i)+25] 
    else:  
        result += i

print("Your encoded message is: ",result)
reversed_result = reversed(result)
print("Your decoded message is: ", reversed_result)
```

Comment: Just like you used it. I don't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

The [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function returns an iterator. You need to loop over this object to get its contents, or convert it to a list.

You could also use slicing to reverse the string:

```
>>> 'test'[::-1]
'tset'
```

Note this does not reverse the encoding - it just reverses the letters in the string. You'll have to write a decode function to reverse encode something. As your caesar cipher's encode is the same as the decode, you could do the following:

```
import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)


def encode(text):
    result = ''
    for i in list(text.upper()):    
        if i in alphabet:      
            result += alphabet[-alphabet.index(i)+25] 
        else:  
            result += i
    return result

text = input("Your message: ")    
print(text)    


print("Your encoded message is: ", encode(text))
print("Your decoded message is: ", encode(encode(text)))
```

**Output:**

```
Your message: test
test
Your encoded message is:  GVHG
Your decoded message is:  TEST
```

Comment: Guess thats what this is about - getting the "reverse" of the encode function - not reversing strings :)